# Download files (any kind) from server to local through Shiny

Tags: r, file, download, shiny

I am developing a shiny application (shiny-server) which in last instance should be able to allow downloading files (which are hosted in a directory in the server) to the local directory of a user.

I have been looking for this but I have not been able to find a solution so I have started wondering if it is actually possible.

Thank you very much, any help will be very valuable!

Comment: Check [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadButton.html) and [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a normal download button as suggested by @Sumedh

ui.R

```
downloadButton("demo", "Download")
```

server.R

```
output$demo <- downloadHandler(
filename = function(){
    paste("demo","txt",sep=".")
},
content = function(con){
    file.copy("some-file.txt", con)
})
```

Comment: Hi , What if the file name is dynamically created when the user submit a job? How do we enable the new file to be downloaded from browser? Or how to create a dynamic a href?

Comment: The filename is created here on the server side. Instead of hardcoding the filename you can use a dynamically created one that you can read from a reactive element.