# Download local .db file from local shiny

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny, download

I have my file (example.db) in the same directory with my script, but it doesn't work.
It seems like .db files are not supported from the downloadHandler or I am missing something.
Will there be any work round with the .db files or anything I missed?

Any hints or helps are appreciated!

app.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('download_database', 'Download Database', class = 'pull-right')
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Download Database
  output$download_database <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      'example.db'
    },
    content = function(file) {
      file.copy('example.db', file)
    }
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I was trying to implement this thread to make my app downloadable from my local .db file. ([Download files (any kind) from server to local through Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639022/download-files-any-kind-from-server-to-local-through-shiny))

Comment: As in the post you referenced and also mentioned in the docs (`? downloadHandler`) try with `downloadButton` instead of `actionButton`.

Comment: ahhh yes, I missed a very obvious one and didn't recognize before seeing this...  It works fine now. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `downloadHandler()`, you should use `downloadButton()` instead of `actionButton()`.

The reason for this is due to HTML that each R function generates. To enable a download link (or button) in HTML, you should have an anchor tag similar to `<a href="path/to/file.txt" download>`.

Breaking this down, we have the following:

- `<a>` - defines a hyperlink.
- `href="path/to/file.txt"` - specifies the file to be downloaded (`downloadHandler()` in the server takes care of this).
- `download` - an attribute to enable downloading for the tag.

When generating HTML with Shiny functions:

- `actionButton()` generates something like `<button class="btn">`.
- `downloadButton()` generates something like `<a href = "path/to/example.db" class="btn" download>`. (which also has CSS styling as a button rather than a link via the `class` attribute).

Therefore, the `downloadButton` is what you need in this case.

Comment: I haven't thought of looking at my very obvious error but looking other things around. Thank you so much!